# i dont get any output with python pyperclip module i dont know where the problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, encryption, python-module

```py
import  pyperclip

#Cesar Chiper
#The String to be encrypt or decrypted

message = "This is my secret message"

#The encryption /decryption key

key = 13

#Tell the program to encrypt/decrypt
mode = "encrypt"

#Every possible sympol to encrypt or decrypt from the message

letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

#Stores message

translated=""

message = message.upper()

#run the encryption/decryption code in each symbol in the message string

for symbol in message:
  if symbol in letters:
    #get the encypted or deycrypted number for this symbol
    num = letters.find(symbol)
    if mode == "encrypt":
      num = num + key
    elif mode == "decrypt":
      num = num - key

      #handle the wrap around if num is larger than lenght of letters or less than 0

      if num >= len(letters):
        num = num - len(letters)
      elif num < 0:
        num = num + len(letters)

#ad encrypted/decrypted number symbol at the end of translted
        translated = translated + letters[num]

      else:

  #Just add the symbol without encrypting/decrypting
       translated = translated + symbol

#print the encrypted/decrypted to screen
print(translated)

  #copy the encrypted/decrypted string to clipoard
pyperclip.copy(translated)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei. I see that no problem in your code but the **indent**.

- First. The code wit comment `#handle the wrap around if num is larger than lenght of letters or less than 0` have to remove one indent(these must take in the same block with 2 desicions before). The `translated = translated + letters[num]` have to put at the same block with previous desicion
- Second. The last `else` statement have to put at the same block with first `if`(if symbol in letters)

Here it is:

```
import pyperclip

message = "This is my secret message"
key = 13
mode = "encrypt"
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
translated=""
message = message.upper()

for symbol in message:
  if symbol in letters:
    num = letters.find(symbol)
    if mode == "encrypt":
      num = num + key
    elif mode == "decrypt":
      num = num - key
    if num >= len(letters):
      num = num - len(letters)
    elif num < 0:
      num = num + len(letters)
    translated = translated + letters[num]
  else:
    translated = translated + symbol
print(translated)
pyperclip.copy(translated)
```

The Output will be: `GUVF VF ZL FRPERG ZRFFNTR`
(Sorry bad english)